# luks encrypted root partition and swiss keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, encryption, luks, xubuntu

I am using Xubuntu 16.04 with a luks encrypted root partition. I have to type my password during boot. I use a swiss keyboard to type the password, but the system doesn't accept it. On boot the keyboard layout is us. How can I change the keyboard layout to ch on boot?